# How do I add another class and make it follow the player? (In PyGame)

Tags: python, class, pygame

I'm making a little game for fun with pygame but so far I've only been able to create the player now I want to add another class the class is supposed to follow the player and if it touches the player for a set amount of time the player dies. I'd like to learn how to do it for other projects of mine so I'd prefer a more general answer for beginners with pygame.

I've already tried to create the class based on this class.:

```
class Char(pygame.sprite.Sprite):    
    def __init__(self, color, pos, radius, width):    
        super().__init__()    
        self.image = pygame.Surface([radius*2, radius*2])    
        self.image.fill(WHITE)    
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)    
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image, color, [radius, radius], radius, width)   
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

Which evidently didn't work and then I gave up because everything I could think of was beyond that what I know about pygame.

```
import pygame    
import turtle    
import time    
import math    
import random    
import sys    
import os    
pygame.init()    

WHITE = (255,255,255)    
GREEN = (0,255,0)    
BGColor = (117,168,55)    
RED = (255,0,0)    
BLUE = (0,0,255)    
BLACK = (0,0,0)    
MOVE = 2.5    

size = (1200, 620)    
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)    
pygame.display.set_caption("Zombie Game")    

class Char(pygame.sprite.Sprite):    
    def __init__(self, color, pos, radius, width):    
        super().__init__()    
        self.image = pygame.Surface([radius*2, radius*2])    
        self.image.fill(WHITE)    
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)    
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image, color, [radius, radius], radius, width)   
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()    

    def moveRight(self, pixels):    
        self.rect.x += pixels
        pass    

    def moveLeft(self, pixels):    
        self.rect.x -= pixels
        pass    

    def moveUp(self, pixels):    
        self.rect.y -= pixels
        pass    

    def moveDown(self, pixels):    
        self.rect.y += pixels
        pass    


all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()    

playerChar = Char(BLUE, [0, 0], 30, 0)    
playerChar.rect.x = 0    
playerChar.rect.y = 0    

all_sprites_list.add(playerChar)    

carryOn = True    
clock = pygame.time.Clock()    

while carryOn:    
    for event in pygame.event.get():    
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:    
            carryOn=False    
        elif event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:    
            if event.key==pygame.K_x:    
                carryOn=False    

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()    
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:    
        playerChar.moveLeft(MOVE)    
    if keys[pygame.K_d]:    
        playerChar.moveRight(MOVE)    
    if keys[pygame.K_w]:    
        playerChar.moveUp(MOVE)    
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:    
        playerChar.moveDown(MOVE)    

    screen.fill(BGColor) 
    screen.blit(playerChar.image,playerChar.rect)
    pygame.display.flip()    
    clock.tick(60)    
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: How far into the second class can you get? Is it just getting the new sprite to follow the player that you're having trouble with? Could you let us know what you've tried so far?

Comment: I can't even get the second class to show.

Comment: That's no good.  I would start with a second instance of your Char class (just to make sure you can put multiple sprites on screen at a time).  Once that works create a Char2 class that's exactly the same as Char class.  If you can make an instance of both then it's a matter of making small adjustments to the Char class until you have your zombie.

Comment: Could you please provide examples and dumb it down a little since I just started. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I myself got it to work after fiddling around with it a little  I used the code provided in the answer above:

```
playerChar1 = Char(BLUE, [0, 0], 30, 0) 
playerChar2 = Char(BLUE, [0, 30], 30, 0) 
playerChar3 = Char(BLUE, [30, 0], 30, 0)
```

I just forgot to add this in the main loop of my program:

```
screen.blit(playerChar1.image,playerChar1.rect)
screen.blit(playerChar2.image,playerChar2.rect)
screen.blit(playerChar3.image,playerChar3.rect)
```

That got it to work!
The following part I found in another question on this website.

Answer (score 2):

To get to the root of this problem we'll need to get some more information.  Being unable to 'get the second class to show up' could be a million different things.  To turn this into a question I can help with you can do a few tests.

The first I would suggest is making several instances  of your class.  For example:

```
playerChar1 = Char(BLUE, [0, 0], 30, 0) 
playerChar2 = Char(BLUE, [0, 30], 30, 0) 
playerChar3 = Char(BLUE, [30, 0], 30, 0)
```

Does this make 3 characters in different spots? If not maybe you are drawing over all but the newest character?

Provided you can create multiple instances of your Char class, next we want a second class.  We'll start with your char class and just rename it `Char2`:

```
class Char2(pygame.sprite.Sprite):    
    def __init__(self, color, pos, radius, width):    
        super().__init__()    
        self.image = pygame.Surface([radius*2, radius*2])    
        self.image.fill(WHITE)    
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)    
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image, color, [radius, radius], radius, width)   
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()    

    def moveRight(self, pixels):    
        self.rect.x += pixels
        pass    

    def moveLeft(self, pixels):    
        self.rect.x -= pixels
        pass    

    def moveUp(self, pixels):    
        self.rect.y -= pixels
        pass    

    def moveDown(self, pixels):    
        self.rect.y += pixels
        pass
```

Literally the same stuff everywhere inside.  Just like before, can you make instances of this class? Do they show up on screen?

Finally, if the second class shows up all you need to do is tweak the logic in that second class until it acts like the Zombie you want.

Comment: Unfortunatly it doesn't create a new character
Edit: writing something  within these [] doesn't move my existing char either but changing this:
    playerChar.rect.y = 0    
changes my characters position.

Comment: I also read somewhere  else that the classes might share the same position but yet I don't know  how to fix that.